# ScrollToBottom function not working in React hook reactjs

Tags: reactjs

The class method below scroll message as messages is being append and it's working fine.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
//const messagesEndRef = React.createRef();
//const el = React.createRef();

this.el = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
message: '',
messages: [],
};

  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
const message = 'Hello everyone';

// messages concat goes here
 this.scrollToBottom();

  }

scrollToBottom() { 
this.el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
}
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="">
 {this.state.messages.map((e, i) => (
              <div key={i}>
        
<div"> {e.message}</div> 
<div ref={el => { this.el = el; }} ></div>

              </div>
            ))}
       
        </div>

<div>
 <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
</div>


      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my issue: I am trying to rewrite the code above to use functional React hook method by it throws error

```
 el.scrollIntoView is not a function scrollToBottom@https://localhost:9000/
```

I think the error is caused by **scrollToBottom() function**.

```
function App() {
const el = React.createRef();
const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);


  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
const message = 'Hello everyone';

// messages concat goes here
scrollToBottom();

  }

function scrollToBottom() { 
el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
}


    return (
      <div>
        <div className="">
 {messages.map((e, i) => (
              <div key={i}>
        
<div"> {e.message}</div> 
<div ref={el => {el = el; }} ></div>

              </div>
            ))}
       
        </div>

<div>
 <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
</div>


      </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to change the `el.scrollIntoView()` call to be:

```
el.current.scrollIntoView()
```

Secondly, change the ref from a function to be an assignment - you cannot reassign a value to a constant variable (el) so I'm not sure how your function ref was compiling in the first place.

Finally, with hooks you should use `useRef` instead of `createRef`:

```
const el = useRef(null);

/** -- snip -- **/

<div ref={el} ></div>
```

Read more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have  as you said but am still having the error pointed above `el.scrollIntoView is not a function scrollToBottom@https://localhost:9000/`

Comment: did you try el.current.scrollIntoView